# Microsoft Interop PowerPoint method for slide affects another slide

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I am using Microsoft.Interop.PowerPoint in my app and so code below:

`thisSlide.Design = thatSlide.Design;`,

where thisSlide is from current presentation and thatSlide is from another, affects not only thisSlide, but slide after it too and applies current thatSlide's design to itself.

So my question is, is there any workaround to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The Design object sets the Slide Master for the presentation. The slide master affects all slides using the same master. Most likely, you want to set the **Slide Layout**:

```
objSlide1.CustomLayout = objSlide2.CustomLayout
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems, it is not supposed to work using slides from different presentations, because PowerPoint reloads.

Comment: I don't what you mean by "PowerPoint reloads". It crashes? Restarts? Please clarify.
Because of the generally incompatible presentations that most users create, slides from different presentations will bring their own slide layouts with them. Most likely none of these layouts will format other slides successfully, because they'll have different numbers and types of placeholders. Here's an article of mine outlining the 5 criteria that must be met to successfully reuse slides: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2018/11/legacy-slides-brandwares-best-practices/

Comment: Yes, it restarts. Yes, I agree with that it will bring it's layouts when being inserted in my presentation (basically by InsertFromFile only one layout - its own), but the issue is that it will not bring actually MasterSlide automatically, so I am looking for a way, where I would be able to insert Master and set to inserted file it's layout, which matches with the layout from other presentation I open with Interop the way it will not affect other slides. It can easily be done by OpenXML, but I wonder, is there any way to do that using Interop.